# Update large object partially on events

Tags: javascript

I am having a large object which might grow in size. I want to update some properties on each event, there are multiple events like click, navigating to specific routes, taking prints and a lot more. I am able to do it using `Object.assign(targetObject, keys)`. Currently, I am using the `Assign` method, adding a sample object:

```
const reportingObject = {
   key1: 'value1',
   key2: 'value2',
   .
   .
   .
   key30: 'value30',
}
```

For example, On Click event, I am updating keys `key1` to `key 4` and on other events I want to update `key10` to `key20`. It works fine with the `object.assign` method.

I want to know is there any more efficient method or way to do this. As in long run, it will be difficult to manage the object properties. Can we use proxy for such scenarios or any other JS method? I have gone through many links, but didn't find anything.

Comment: You wrong place, post it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object.assign is fine, but here is another way to do that with destructing.

```
let obj1 = {key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3, key4: 4, key5: 5};
let obj2 = {key2: 6, key3: 6};
let obj3 = {...obj1, ...obj2};
let obj4 = Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: No, the keys could be anything and they are dynamic. and I need to update a part of object.

Comment: So it's even easier:
 reportingObject[keyName] = newValue;
It also works with unexisting *keyName*

Comment: That is doable but what if I need to update 20 keys at a time? How can we efficiently do that?

Comment: I've just edited the answer. Check this out.

Comment: It could be a way, but I need to maintain objects to keep the values and keys. I am following Object.assign, my question is there any other efficient way for doing the same?